# I am getting the following error Javascript runtime error: function expected

Tags: javascript

The code works ok until a call a page method. 
This is the function that is giving trouble

```
SetCellValueFromKey = (row, CellName, totalQty);
```

the function is an another js file

```
function SetCellValueFromKey(theRow, theKey, setValue) {
    theRow.get_cellByColumnKey(theKey).set_value(setValue);
}
```

here is my page method function

```
 PageMethods.GetSalesOrderInfo(dteStartDate, dteEndDate, ProductsArray, GetSalesOrderInfoCallSuccess, GetSalesOrderInfoCallFailed);
 return false;
```

Here is the GetSalesOrderInfoCallSuccess function

```
function GetSalesOrderInfoCallSuccess(result) {

     var lbActualSales = document.getElementById("<%=lbActualSales.ClientID%>");
     var hdnWeekNumOfWeekYear = document.getElementById("<%=hdnWeekNumOfWeekYear.ClientID%>").value;
     // Code to handle a Success from 'GetActualSalesInfoCallSuccess'
     //if result it not null, parse the data
     if (result != null) {
         var jsResult = JSON.parse(result);

         //clear the Actual Sales list box  
         var NumRows = lbActualSales.length;
         if (NumRows != 0) {
             for (var i = NumRows - 1; i >= 0 ; i--) {
                 //remove the row  
                 lbActualSales.options.remove(i);
             }
         }
         NumRows = jsResult.length;
         var optionNum = 0;
         if (NumRows > 0) {
             for (var i = 0; i < NumRows; i++) {
                 var dataRow = jsResult[i];                   
                 //Add the new data into Actual Sales ListBox 
                 var option = "option" + optionNum;
                 option = document.createElement("option");
                 lbActualSales.options.add(option, lbActualSales.options.length);
                 strRow = [dataRow.SalesOrderId] + "|" + [dataRow.ProductId] + "|" + [dataRow.Quantity] + "|" + [dataRow.Weight] + "|" + [dataRow.UnitPrice] + "|" + [dataRow.TotalPrice] + "|" + [dataRow.ListPrice] + "|" + [dataRow.SalesOrderNum] + "|" + [dataRow.CustomerId] + "|" + [dataRow.DateCreated] + "|" + [dataRow.CustomerName] + "|" + [dataRow.UnitOfSale] + "|" + [dataRow.Product_Name] + "|" + [dataRow.Week] + "|" + [dataRow.OrderType];
                 option.text = strRow;
                 option.value = [dataRow.ProductId] + "|" + [dataRow.Week];
                 optionNum = optionNum + 1;
             }
         }             

         var grid = getGrid("<%=wdgSalesForecast.ClientID%>");
         var search = "";
         var totalQty = 0;
         NumRows = lbActualSales.length;
         //for each row in grid get the ProductId and the week to search into the listBox 
         for (var i = 0; i < grid.get_rows().get_length() ; i++) {
             var row = grid.get_rows().get_row(i);
             var productId = getCellValueFromKey(row, "ProductId");
             search = productId;
             //loop through the row to change each value for Actual Sales 
             for (var j = 0; j < row.get_cellCount() ; j++) {
                 var cell = row.get_cell(j);
                 var CellName = cell._column._key;                    
                 //get the week num and build a string "search"
                 if (CellName.search("ActAmtWk") > -1) {
                     var WeekNum = CellName.split("ActAmtWk");
                     WeekNum = WeekNum.pop();
                     var weekNumOfYear = parseInt(WeekNum) + parseInt(hdnWeekNumOfWeekYear) - 1;
                     search = search.concat("|");
                     search = search.concat(weekNumOfYear);

                     //loop through the Actual Sales List box and search for the product for the specific week 
                     for (var count = 0; count < NumRows; count++) {
                         if (search == lbActualSales.options[count].value) {
                             var splitValues = lbActualSales.options[count].text.split("|");
                             // Calculate the Qty                       
                             totalQty = totalQty + parseInt(splitValues[7]);
                         }
                     }
                     //update the Forecast Grid cell with the New Value
                     SetCellValueFromKey = (row, CellName, totalQty);
                 }
                 //reset my search string and totalQty
                 search = productId;
                 totalQty = 0;
             } 
         }
         UpdateDemandForecast();

     }//end of result test 
  alert('Data Updated successfully');
 }//end of function `
```

ps. I call others functions from the same js file and I have no problem with.

Answer (score 1):

Your line of code is an assignment statement, which is why it's causing you problems:

```
SetCellValueFromKey = (row, CellName, totalQty);
```

You've already created the function `SetCellValueFromKey(theRow, theKey, setValue)` so to call that function, you should use:

```
SetCellValueFromKey(row, CellName, totalQty);
```

Comment: Thank you so much ... too long looking at the code could not see this stupid mistake .. I called that function many times in the rest of the code. Sorry waste your time :)

Comment: No problem at all! Sometimes (ie. regularly) the hardest issues to resolve are the easiest ones. It's really easy to gloss over an obvious mistake in your own code. We've all done it!

Answer (score 1):

Try giving following

```
SetCellValueFromKey(row, CellName, totalQty);
```

instead of

`SetCellValueFromKey = (row, CellName, totalQty);`

Comment: Thank you so much ... too long looking at the code could not see this stupid mistake .. I called that function many times in the rest of the code. Sorry waste your time :)